# Dirichlet form of 2 Complex Functions is a conformal invariant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let complex functions $g,h$ be defined on a bounded domain $U$. The Dirichlet form of $g$ and $h$ is:
$$
D_U(g,h)=\int\int_U \left [ \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \bar{h}}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\frac{\partial \bar{h}}{\partial y} \right ] dxdy
$$

I am trying to show that the Dirichlet form is conformal invariant: Let $z = f(\xi)$ be a 1-1 analytic function from a bounded domain $V$ to $U$, then:
$$
D_U(g,h)=D_V(g \circ f, h \circ f)
$$

I can see quite clearly the image of this theorem. However, I couldn't find a way to transform the integral from in $V$ to in $U$.

Answer (score 0):

Expressing the partial derivatives as column vectors, we have $D_U(g,h)=\int\int_U\left[\left(\frac{\partial\bar{h}}{\partial (x, y)}\right)^T  \frac{\partial g}{\partial (x, y)}\right]dxdy.$

The Jacobian matrix of $f$ can be written as $f'=\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(s,t)}=\rm{Re}(f') \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right) + \rm{Im}(f') \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right).$

Now $\left[\left(\frac{\partial\bar{h}}{\partial (s, t)}\right)^T  \frac{\partial g}{\partial (s, t)}\right]dsdt=\left[\left({f}'\frac{\partial\bar{h}}{\partial (x, y)}\right)^T  f' \frac{\partial g}{\partial (x, y)}\right]dsdt=\left[\left(\frac{\partial\bar{h}}{\partial (x, y)}\right)^T   \frac{\partial g}{\partial (x, y)}\right][(\rm{Re}(f')^2-\rm{Im}(f')^2)dsdt]=\left[\left(\frac{\partial\bar{h}}{\partial (x, y)}\right)^T \frac{\partial g}{\partial (x, y)}\right]dxdy.$